# State not updating in dialog box when using providers

Tags: flutter, dialog, provider, state-management

> I am trying to open a dialog box to let users add 2 things:

1. 1- Video thumbnail(Image file)
2. Video URL(String)

The user taps on an Inkwell which opens the dialog box, then the user clicks the inkwell in the dialog box to pick a video thumbnail i.e image file. The image file gets set, but it doesn't update the state of the inkwell which needs to show the picked file. The state is updated after hot reload. I am using the provider to set the image file and using its instance to check if the file is picked or not.

Change Notifier ->

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class GetThumbnailImage extends ChangeNotifier {
  PickedFile? image;

  Future setImage(var file) async {
    image = file;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Widgets using the change notifier ->

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          getVideoImage().then((image) {
            print(image);
            if (image != null) {
              _imageInstance.setImage(image);
            }
          });
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          child: Center(
            child: _imageInstance.image == null
                ? SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    child: FadeInImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          apiBase + productId.toString() + apiLaterPart),
                      placeholder:
                          AssetImage("assets/images/Otherimages/addvideo.jpg"),
                      imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                        return Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/Otherimages/addvideo.jpg',
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
                      },
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  )
                : Image.file(
                    File(_imageInstance.image!.path),
                  ),
          ),
        ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a consumer widget on top of widgets that you want to rebuild

```dart
                 Center(
                      child: Consumer<GetThumbnailImage>(
                        builder:(context, model, child) => model.image == null
                            ? SizedBox(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 200,
                                child: FadeInImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(apiBase +
                                      productId.toString() +
                                      apiLaterPart),
                                  placeholder: AssetImage(
                                      "assets/images/Otherimages/addvideo.jpg"),
                                  imageErrorBuilder:
                                      (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                    return Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/Otherimages/addvideo.jpg',
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
                                  },
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Image.file(
                                File(model.image!.path),
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked. Marked as correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for this!  This was a huge help for me today!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is "dialog is not part of the widget tree"

Your code is not complete to help but here are some suggestions.

Solution 1.

You can pass the `context` of the parent widget to the dialog box, So the dialog box should also behave like a part of the widget tree

Solution 2. (Better)

Use something like this in the `showDialogBox` method...

```dart
final image = context.watch<GetThumbnailImage>();
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: image
      child: Dialog(...)
   );
```

Now you can use instance of provider in the dialog box and it will also rebuild the widget tree to update the UI

Comment: Thanks, Usama, I got the logic, and you were right, but for some reason, it didn't work. Looks like I had to use the consumer widget.

Comment: Consumer is working because you are passing parent's context to it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

made this changes to your code and try

```
class GetThumbnailImage extends ChangeNotifier {
  PickedFile? _image;
  
  PickedFile get image => _image;

  Future setImage(var file) async {
    _image = file;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```